# Coldfusion limit cfloop to 10

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

I'm working with quite a large array of items in a cfloop. I would like to pare this down and add pagination. Is there anyway in my cfloop to limit the array to the first 10?

I have

```
<cfloop array="#qryItems#" index="index">
```

I have tried turning it into a condition loop with no luck and a few other things. I haven't touched coldfusion in a while and am a little rusty. Google is not helping haha

I have tried

```
<cfloop from="1" to="10" array="#qryItems#" index="index">
```

and have also tried max_rows

```
 <cfloop maxrows="10" array="#qryItems#" index="index">
```

each time I get the error message

"Attribute validation error for tag CFLOOP."

Comment: you can use `cfbreak`

Comment: @Lashane It's a very large chunk of code in the cfoutput so I was trying to avoid having to edit it, but I'll try anything.

Comment: Instead of limiting the loop to 10 iterations, why not edit the thing that defines the array to only return 10 elements? If it's defined by a query, you'll get much better performance by doing the pagination in the database and only returning the requested page's records.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno because that's not how the app is setup and that's a lot more work than the time I was given to complete this. That's perfect world and unfortunately I'm not in perfect world.

Comment: @zazvorniki - Well if it is a growing data set, eventually performance will start to tank. So paginating on the db side is really the way to go.  If you absolutely must paginate after the fact, a quick search should turn up plenty of pagination logic examples and/or [cfc's such as this one](http://paginationcfc.riaforge.org/). Essentially, you just need the basic logic to calculate the total pages in sets of N records. Then use a `cfloop` with `start/endRow` instead of `cfloop array="..."`

Comment: @Leigh It's not a growing set of data, it's stagnant and we may (very little chance) be adding one or two more items. I don't really have access to the db side of this so even though that's what I would like to do I cannot. I already have the pagination in place and the array...I just need to limit this loop.

Comment: EDIT: *I already have the pagination in place* Then what is the issue? If you already figured out how to calculate the starting and ending record or index, do what I mentioned above, ie [*"...use a from/to cfloop with `start/endRow` instead of `cfloop array="..."`"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350595/coldfusion-limit-cfloop-to-10#comment69904364_41350595).  Otherwise, please update your question with the new code and any error messages.

Comment: @Leigh I edited my answer. Each time I add either maxrows or a from/to then I get back an error. Whlie the pagination is working, it's not limiting the items coming back. So you can go back and forth between pages, but the loop is still displaying all the results.

Comment: @zazvorniki - Sorry, brain glitch. I am incorrectly mixing loop attributes. `start/EndRow` only work with queries. See my example below.

Answer (score 2):

```
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="index">
    <!--- Then do your business with array elements qryItems[index], that is, with qryItems[1], qryItems[2],..., qryItems[10] --->
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I have tried this. I just get back an error "
Attribute validation error for tag CFLOOP."

Comment: @zazvorniki You must have had something else wrong because this should work. If you post the code that you tried we can probably point out the issue. Just [edit your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41350595/edit) and add the code there.

Comment: @Miguel-F I'm not changing anything else in the code and the code has been stable for over a year now. I posted above the code I have tried.

Comment: @zazvorniki Notice the lack of the array attribute in BKBK code. If you are iterating over a count, the index variable is the count. When you iterate over an array, the index variable is the element value. You can't iterate on a count and an array in one cfloop.

Comment: @Twillen So I can't have an array? I had that in my original post and is the only way I can get my data. Is there anyway to accomplish this with the array?

Comment: @zazvorniki - The above does not quite do what you need. However, it would if you modify the `from` and `to` values to be the start/end position of the elements you want to display.  The loop `index` value then becomes a number. Inside the loop, use that position to get the appropriate *element*, or data, from the array which you can use the same way as before. [Runnable example](http://trycf.com/gist/1833166b313d7602c2fbf991a02fd431/acf2016?theme=monokai)

Answer (score 1):

There is no combination of attributes for `cfloop` to accomplish what your expecting. As BKBK suggested, you'll need to use a `from/to` loop to output a select group of records. If I understand your requirements correctly, I would update your `cfloop` with a new index variable as well, and then set the old variable by referencing the array element.

The two `cfloops` below output the same data, with the second displaying only the records in the pagination range.

```
<cfset qryItems = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'a','b','c','d'] />
<cfoutput>
    <!--- Current loop: Outputs all records --->
    <cfloop array="#qryItems#" index="index">
        #index#
    </cfloop>
    <cfset paginationStart = 1 />
    <cfset paginationEnd = 10 />
    <!--- Only the range of of records requested --->
    <cfloop from="#paginationStart#" to="#paginationEnd#" index="indexNumber">
        <cfset index = qryItems[indexNumber] />
        <!--- code remain the same --->
        #index#
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Yes, though I think they actually want the `from/to` to be dynamic so it can be use with pagination code to display elements X through Y, instead of always displaying the first 10 elements. [Example](http://trycf.com/gist/1833166b313d7602c2fbf991a02fd431/acf2016?theme=monokai).

Comment: Thanks @Leigh I've gone and updated my example to include variables for the pagination like in your example.